# Is it possible to export items currently in workflow?

Tags: content-porter-2013

It seems that SDL Content Porter 2013 SP1 can only export items from the *last approved version*.

Is it possible to export items that are currently in workflow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The following description is given in the [Export constraints](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Content%20Porter-v1/GUID-B5E7808D-28A8-4FFD-830A-5E7744B991F7) section of the online documentation:

> ### Items in workflow
>
> You cannot export a version of an item that is in workflow, not even
>   if the item is assigned to the user who is performing the transfer.
>
> Instead, the version that will be exported is the last version that
>   either finished a workflow process or was saved outside a workflow
>   process. If there is no last version to export (that is, if the item
>   is in its first workflow process), you cannot export the item at all.
>
> For best results, make sure that all finished items are no longer in
>   workflow when you perform an export.

If it's essential that you have the latest version (currently in Workflow), then you're going to have to complete the Workflow process.

Assuming that your items are in Production, then you may want to take a copy of your CM database, restore this to another environment, complete the Workflow process for those items and then export them from there.